# What is the equivalent of mkdir -p on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I've been unable to find help files on Windows for things like `MD`, `mkdir` or `new-item`. Doing `update-help` just throws errors.

How do I do `mkdir -p` on Windows 10 in Command Prompt?

I want to create a directory even if that directory already exists.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir` of Windows 10 does not support `-p` or `/p` or an equivalent flag.

If you want realize the `-p` functionality according to Unix operating systems you can do that in one line as follows:

```
set MKDIR_DIR=D:\XYZ\123\ABC && if not exist %MKDIR_DIR% mkdir %MKDIR_DIR%
```

Replace `D:\XYZ\123\ABC` with the desired directory.

Comment: you don't even need to use variables here, just doing a `if not exist <dir> mkdir <dir>` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mkdir /?` to get information on the command. `-p` is not a flag in Windows, parent/intermediate directories will be created if command extensions are turned on.

See [this Microsoft documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490930.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Actually, I want to be able to create a directory even if it already exists. I've updated my question.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want the command to delete the existing directory and recreate it if it already exists?

Comment: Yes, then make a new one.

Comment: mkdir cannot do that. You'll have to either write a batch script that checks every directory in the path, empties and deletes if it exists, and then creates it. Here's a starter guide for batch: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting


Alternatively, you can use powershell, a command like `New-Item path -type directory -force` where `path` is the path should do it. Here is info on new-item: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx

Comment: Yes. Microsoft documentation CLAIMS that. But it does NOT work:

`D:\>SETLOCAL enableextensions && mkdir D:\XYZ\ABC\123 && ENDLOCAL`
`Das Verzeichnis oder die Datei kann nicht erstellt werden.`

`D:\>SETLOCAL enableextensions && mkdir D:\XYZ && ENDLOCAL`

`D:\>SETLOCAL enableextensions && mkdir D:\XYZ\ABC && ENDLOCAL`

`D:\>DIR D:\XYZ\ABC`

` Verzeichnis von D:\XYZ\ABC`

Answer (score 0):

Since `mkdir` in Windows 10 (even with command extensions enabled) does *not* the job, here is the content of my `mkdir.bat` that DOES it for a `%path%` at a `%drive%` :)

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

REM ## Create directory structure levelwise since there is nothing like "mkdir -p"

REM ## substitute "\" with ";"
SET "pathParts=%path:\=;%"

REM ## iterate over a list of the tokens between " ", ",", ";" or "=" 
SET pathToMake=%drive%

FOR %%d IN (%pathParts::= %) DO (
    SET pathToMake=!pathToMake!\%%d
    ECHO !pathToMake!
    IF NOT EXIST !pathToMake! MKDIR !pathToMake!
)
```

Just call it like that:

```
D:\>SET drive=D:

D:\>SET path=XYZ\123\ABC

D:\>mkdir.bat
D:\XYZ
D:\XYZ\123
D:\XYZ\123\ABC
```

And et voilà: `D:\XYZ\123\ABC` exists :)

Comment: with `SETLOCAL enableextensions` the extensions are already enabled and mkdir will automatically creates all the necessasry sub folders. No need for such a complex batch script

Comment: indeed - (now) the "command extensioned" *mkdir* DOES the job :-o
Thanks, @phuclv! :)

Answer (score -1):

There is very easy solution in windows. -p is not required at all.
If you want to create nested folders then write like below:

```
mkdir \Taxes\Property\Current
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mkdir

Answer (score -1):

On Windows 11 Pro using bash this command did the job for me:

**mkdir.exe -p folder/subFolder**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mkdir

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).